# Rank the following radicals in order of decreasing stability

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, stability, radicals, aromaticity

**Question**

> Rank the following radicals in order of decreasing stability
>   [image][image][image][image]

Aromaticity makes a cyclic compund more stable. Here, 1 and 3 are aromatic since they follow Huckels rule(Or am I wrong here?). So, I thought maybe 3 is most stable followed by 1, then followed by 2 and 4(I dont know which is more stable out of 2 and 4). But, that's not the case. 3 is most stable, but the next stable one is 2 and not 1. I don't get how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Here, 1 and 3 are aromatic since they follow Huckels rule(Or am I wrong here?

Yes you're wrong over here, for applying the Huckel's rule the compound must be a closed circuit of delocalized electrons. In both the cases the circuits are not closed

---

If you're not aware of [Conjugation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugated_system) then give that a read .
Now 
The most stable compound is 3 since the extent of conjugation is the greatest i.e 2 pi bonds.

3 is more stable than 4. Even though 4 is aromatic it is an **aryl** free radical the p orbital containing the radical is out of the plane and can't be stabilized through resonance/Hyperconjugation.
In fact I would say that option 4 is the least stable compound .

The second most stable compound is is 2 since it is stabilized via resonance which is more effective than Hyperconjugation; 1 is stabilized by Hyperconjugation.

**3 is more stable than 2** since the extent of conjugation is greater.

The order of stability will be
$$\mathrm{3 > 2 > 1 > 4}$$

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get what closed circuit means. Would you please explain? I would be really grateful!

Comment: I meant that the loop should be closed see this [PDF](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://web.chem.ucla.edu/~harding/tutorials/polycyclic_aromaticity.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwj1rYmIvPPZAhUC3o8KHTS6DXoQFgggMAE&usg=AOvVaw2WJDUtU4ttI0S2FjqG_RV3) for more details

Comment: So they are open. How? I mean, what is exactly being closed. I am really sorry for bothering, but since I am still at basics, I am confused at petty things as well.

Comment: For the flow of delocalized $\pi$ electrons to take place a complete loop must be the compounds 2 and 4 do not have complete loops you'll notice that the carbont atoms are sp3 hybridized, they are all $\sigma$ bonded . No $\pi$ orbitals are present for the flow of electrons

Comment: Oh, now I get it. I knew about that fact, but just didn't get what loop you meant. Thanks!

Comment: @DivyankaS.Chaudhari It may be otherwise stated as "complete conjugation throughout the ring"